# How to simplify the function printing based on the multiple condition

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is formatting a string based on the 3 input variables. I've done it using if / else if statements but I believe there should be a simpler way to do it. I have 3 variables and all of them can be either a string or null. I'm using javascript / angular. I can imagine having a similar case with 5 variables which would increase number of if's significant, how to simplify it ?

```
formatDistance(){
let distance;
let swim;
let bike;
let run;
swim = this.sport.swim ? this.sport.swim : null;
bike = this.sport.bike ? this.sport.bike : null;
run = this.sport.run ? this.sport.run : null;

if(swim && bike && run) {
  distance = swim + ' / ' + bike + ' / ' + run; 
}
else if(swim && bike && !run) {
  distance = swim + ' / ' + bike; 
}
else if(swim && !bike && run) {
  distance = swim + ' / ' + run; 
}
else if(!swim && bike && run) {
  distance = bike + ' / ' + run; 
}
else if(!swim && !bike && run) {
  distance = run; 
}
else if(!swim && bike && !run) {
  distance = bike; 
}
else if(swim && !bike && !run) {
  distance = swim; 
}
else {
  distance = '';
}

 return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter together with join. The sequence is defined by the sequence in the array. Substitude any by null and u can see it will join together with /.

Example in snippets below.

```
[swim, bike, run].filter(item => item !== null).join('/')
```

```js
swim = null
bike = null
run = 'c'


console.log('Should return c =>', [swim, bike, run].filter(item => item !== null).join('/'))

swim = 'a'
bike = null
run = 'c'

console.log('Should return a/c =>', [swim, bike, run].filter(item => item !== null).join('/'))


swim = null
bike = 'b'
run = 'c'

console.log('Should return b/c =>', [swim, bike, run].filter(item => item !== null).join('/'))

swim = 'a'
bike = 'b'
run = 'c'

console.log('Should return a/b/c =>', [swim, bike, run].filter(item => item !== null).join('/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
formatDistance(){
    let distance = "";
    let swim;
    let bike;
    let run;
    swim = this.sport.swim ? this.sport.swim : null;
    bike = this.sport.bike ? this.sport.bike : null;
    run = this.sport.run ? this.sport.run : null;
    
    if(swim != null)
      distance = distance + swim + ' / ';
    if(bike != null)
      distance = distance + bike + ' / ';
    if(run != null)
      distance = distance + run + ' / ';
    distance = distance.substring(0, distance.length - 1);
    return distance;
}
```

What i have done is append values based on availability and remove the final `/`